# How can I replace certain value with the mean in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdpAl.png)

I want to replace the -1 with mean of ages, but I keep getting zero and not the mean.

Here's the code
[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4u7i.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Age":[1.2,2,3,-1,0]})

# Output before;
   Age
0  1.2
1  2.0
2  3.0
3 -1.0
4  0.0

df["Age"].replace(-1,df["Age"].mean(),inplace=True)

# Output after replacing;
    Age
0  1.20
1  2.00
2  3.00
3  1.04
4  0.00
```

Comment: it didn't work);

Comment: It seems to be working for me... & also in your 2nd screenshot, seems like you are checking if it has replaced -1 with mean or not by looking at the df.describe() ... maybe that column (Age) has some 0 value in it, that's why it showing the min value as 0, & made you think that -1 is getting replaced with 0 with your code... hehe! ... just saying that because I don't see any issue with your code too... so better you look at the data if Age column has any 0s to start with... otherwise not sure where is the issue...